# Getting 2 non-adjacent columns to work with

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a macro that compares two columns to see whether or not they are the same. This is the function.

```
Sub Compare()
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row 
For i=2 to LastRow
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value Then
        Range("C" & i).Value = True
    Else
        Range("C" & i).Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Right now it is hard coded to compare column A and B then output True/False into column C. What I want to do is have the user select ONLY 2 columns from their excel sheet and then run this macro which then compares the two selected columns by the user. These 2 columns can be non-adjacent to each other, so for example the user can select column A and column K to compare the values between them.

Comment: You are better off doing this with an Array

Comment: Could I have an example on how to do this? Would love to know how I could make it better.

Comment: Comparing non-adjacent columns is just like comparing adjacent ones, so I'm not clear on what your problem is. What are you comparing? ...only the values? Does formatting matter?  What's the end result -- just a single `TRUE`/`FALSE` indicating whether the entire column matches?  An example of what you're working with might be helpful.

Comment: I am comparing strings to one another. For example, "ABC0101" = "ABC0101" then output will be True. "ABC0102" = "ABC0101" Then False.

Comment: ... and with these non-adjacent columns, where is the true/false result supposed to go?

Comment: Oh sorry I missed out the first part of your question @ashleedawg . The problem is that when I select 2 columns from the worksheet, the selection object only has the column before the gap between the 2 columns. If I were to select 3 columns, say column A, B and D. The selection object will get A and B. I would like to have the Selection.Column(3) return the column of D instead of C.

Comment: These true/false results should be placed in a new column at the end of the excel sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the .Areas property of non adjacent columns.

```
Sub CompareTwo()
    dim rng as range, i as long
    set rng = intersect(selection, selection.parent.usedrange)

    if rng.areas.count>1 then
        for i=1 to rng.areas(1).rows.count
            rng.areas(2).cells(i).offset(0, 1) = cbool(rng.areas(1).cells(i).value = rng.areas(2).cells(i).value)
        next i
    else
        for i=1 to rng.rows.count
            rng.cells(i).offset(0, 2) = cbool(rng.cells(i).value = rng.cells(i).value)
        next i
    end if
End Sub
```

To put the results *in a new column at the end of the excel sheet*, use Find with xlPrevious and xlByColumns to locate the last used column then offset 1.

Comment: Could you explain what this line does? `set rng = intersect(selection, selection.parent.usedrange)`

Comment: It truncates full column selection down to the used range on the worksheet so you aren't looping until row 1048576.